# cakephp helper link array css not properly display

Tags: cakephp

I've code that will link to logout page and the logout text have css with font awesome.. below is the code..

```
<? php echo $this->Html->link(__('Logout', true), 
array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'Logout'),
array('class'=>'fa fa-sign-out fa-fw')); ?>
```

But when it display, the menu not display nicely like below.

[Screenshot menu with css](http://s8.postimg.org/lv5mn78nl/Screen_Shot_2015_01_19_at_12_44_06_PM.png)

The problem is at the first logout link. 
1) The highlighted only at the icon logout, not to the all text. 
2) The font also not same with the other text.

The last Logout link i code using normal html code like below.

```
<a href="login.html"><i class="fa fa-sign-out fa-fw"></i> Logout</a>
```

The question, where is the problem in my cakephp coding?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this.

```
echo $this->Html->link(
   '<i class="fa fa-sign-out fa-fw"></i> Logout',
    array(
        'controller'=>'users',
        'action'=>'Logout'
    ),
    array(
        'escape'=>false  //NOTICE THIS LINE ***************
    )
);
```

**Output will be**

```
<a href="login.html"><i class="fa fa-sign-out fa-fw"></i> Logout</a>
```

Comment: Thanks @u2460470.. But output still same as without 'escape'.. Logout font not same with the other text.. I tried to change position for array like below..                                                                                                                 <?php echo $this->Html->link('Logout', array('class'=>'fa fa-sign-out     fa-fw''escape'=>false), array('controller' => 'users','action' => 'Logout'));?>

Comment: razif, tell me when you use <a href="login.html"><i class="fa fa-sign-out fa-fw"></i> Logout</a> , this work perfect or not??

Comment: you are welcome, razif, you should accept my answer because another user know that this answer is perfect.